# Consuming a RESTful service in Reactjs

Tags: jquery, rest, reactjs

im starting with reactjs and i want to make a GET request to a RESTful service, here is my code, can anyone help me please?

```
render: function() {
$.ajax({
  url: "http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting"
}).then(function(data) {
  $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);
  $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
return <div style="background-color: #ffffff">
                    <p class="greeting-id">The ID is </p>
                    <p class="greeting-content">The content is </p>

                </div>;        
    }

}
```

i already load Jquery in the html with react, but i still cant make it work, i'm missing something important?  or there is a better way to do this? i dont want to use another extra thing, just react and Jquery, or is something more necesary?

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make your request in the componentDidMount method and use the setState method to assign the data returned by RESTful service to your component's state. In render method you can access it through this.state.greetingId and this.state.greetingContent properties:

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting"
    }).then(function(data) {
        this.setState({
            greetingId: data.id,
            greetingContent: data.content
        });
    }
)},
render: function() {
    return <div style="background-color: #ffffff">
                <p class="greeting-id">The ID is {this.state.greetingId}</p>
                <p class="greeting-content">The content is {this.state.greetingContent}</p>
            </div>;        
}
```

Refer to the following link for details: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

Comment: thank you, and im having a little trouble, i want to have a login window and then load the list of data from the server, how can i load a new component and unload the previous one?

Comment: You can use conditional operators in your render method and return different components in different cases. You can also use router for switching your login view to some other view. Look at react-router if you prefer this solution: https://github.com/rackt/react-router

Comment: im trying to run the example of the link that you give me, but nothing happens u.u, i need another library other than react and jquery?

Comment: You also need to add a reference to react-router

Comment: this uses react ruoter? https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html im having problems with the mounNode in the react.render, cahngeing it for document.body render the text, but not the info of the server.

Comment: Sorry, did not get what link you mentioned. I gave you the link just to show how it should be written. I updated my initial answer with the code snippet based on your initial code

Comment: ty, the request must be in the componentDidMount method? i need to make the request after taking some info in the inputs, how can i do that? or i move the ajax function t another method?

Comment: If you need to perform request after entering data, it's ok to move the code into another method. You just need to implement the correct workflow: sending request and then setting the state on receiving the data.

Answer (score 1):

So I am trying to answer the subsequent comment to load a different view once login is successful

I would start by having 4 components - Main, Login, SuccessResult, FailureResult

```
    var LoginForm = React.createClass({
  render : function(){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit.bind(this, React.findDOMNode(this.refs.login))}>
        <label for="logininfo">Login Info</label>
        <input id="logininfo" type="search" placeholder="input" ref="login"/>
        <input type="submit" value="LogIn" />
      </form>
      )
  }
});

var SuccessResult = React.createClass({
  render : function(){
    var entries = this.props.data;
    return (
      <div>
        Is success
      </div>
      )
  }
});

var FailureResult = React.createClass({
  render : function(){
    return (
      <div>
        Is failure
      </div>
      )
  }
});

var Main = React.createClass({
  getInitialState : function(){
    return {

    }
  },

  render : function(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.success ? <SuccessResult entries={this.state.result}/> : <LoginForm handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this,'maxea')}/>}
        {this.state.failure ? <FailureResult /> : null}
      </div>
      )
  },
  handleSubmit : function(loginInfo){
    var component = this;
    $.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + loginInfo).
      then(function(response){
        component.setState({
          success : true,
          result : response.data
        })
      } ,
      function(error){
        failure : true
      });
  }
});

// Code goes here  
React.render(
  <Main />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

You can use a componentDidUnmount in any of react components to clean up once you are done with a component.

Comment: im having trouble with this code, i dont have any difference, i click in login but just re render the window and dont do anything, dont display any succes or failure message.

Comment: handleSubmit should send loginInfo. I have edited it now

Comment: i have a login with paswword, i had read that i must do a post request to do that, but dont have a response, i put an alert() or confirm() in the succes and error functions, but any of them are showing up, what can be the problem?

Comment: Hi, i realize why dont show up alerts, i have a problem with the onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit.bind(this, React.findDOMNode(this.refs.login))} 
is there a way to do it with out the bind()?